# How to respond to HTML requests made via AJAX in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to write a Rails controller method that will respond to get requests made both "normally" (e.g. following a link) and via ajax.

Normal Case: The controller should respond with fully decorated HTML using the layout.

Ajax Case: The conroller should respond with the HTML snippet generated by the template (no layout)

Here's the jQuery code, I've created to run on the client side to do the get request.

```
jQuery.get("http://mydomain.com/some_controller/some_action", 
           {}, 
           function(data, textstatus) {
             jQuery("#target").html(data);
           },
           "html");
```

What's the best way to handle this in Rails?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your controller dynamically select whether to use a layout based on `request.xhr?`.

For example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  layout :get_layout

  protected

  def get_layout
    request.xhr? ? nil : 'normal_layout'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

In your controller method, simply do this:

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js if request.xhr?
      format.html { redirect_to :action => "index"}
    end
```

Comment: Ooh - I didn't know about request.xhr? Hope you don't mind if I edit my answer to use that.

Comment: In the context of the question, `format.js` is not the best option since he wants html out of it. And for it to work your js template should generate html, which is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this would be to register new format and [specify it explicitly](http://twitter.com/josevalim/status/7928782685995009#) in urls.

Put this in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias 'text/html', :xhtml
```

Save your template in `some_controller/some_action.xhml.haml`.

And add format to url:
`http://mydomain.com/some_controller/some_action.xhtml`, or, better, use

```
url_for(:controller => :some_controller, :action => :some_action, :format => :xhtml)
```

or, even better, path helpers (if you are restful enough):

```
some_controller_some_action_imaginary_path(:format => :xhtml)
```

Mind, that no explicit `respond_to` dispatching is required for this to work.

This technique might be an overkill if all you want is toggle layout for the same template, but if normal and ajax versions are different, then it is certainly a way to go.

**EDIT:**
The just released jQuery 1.5.1 brings the option to specify mime type in `$.ajax()`:

> **mimeType**: A mime type to override the
>   XHR mime type.

This may be an alternative to explicit format in urls, though I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: This is a great unobtrusive solution. However, instead of modifying the URL, I like to simply use:

`respond_to :xhtml if request.xhr?`

in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a new version of rails you can just append .js onto the path and it will infer that the request is a JavaScript call