# form_tag with :remote => true does not update div, skips to separate page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to update a div based on a form submit. I am on Rails 3.1.1. I am trying to adapt someone else's [recipe](http://jmvidal.cse.sc.edu/talks/rubyonrails/form_remote_tag.html). My code in the view is something like this in `main.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<div id='seq_search'>
  <%= form_tag(:remote => true, :update => 'seq_select', :action => 'select')  do %>
    <p>
      <%= search_field_tag  :query, '', :size => 45 %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%=submit_tag "Submit", :disable_wth => "Adding ..."%>
    </p>
   <% end %>
</div>

<div id='seq_select'>

</div>
```

The controller looks like

```
class SearchAjaxController < ApplicationController
  def main
  end
  def select
      render :text => '<li> '+params[:query] + ' </li>'
  end
end
```

However, when I enter something in the text box and press submit, instead of updating the div, it goes off to another page rendering just the output of the `select` method of the controller.

If I look at the page source of the form, it is something like this:

```
<div id='seq_search'>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search_ajax/select?remote=true&amp;update=seq_select" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="wlOm4H7GvZAQoIVpjxPLqHAQLOIpJ4V5r0WYEpvCCrQ=" /></div>
    <p>
      <input id="query" name="query" size="45" type="search" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input disable_wth="Adding ..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form></div>

<div id='seq_select'>

</div>
```

It seems that the form is simply passing `remote=true&amp;update=seq_select` as arguments to the controller's method/function. Is this what is supposed to happen?

**Update:**

So I tried to add to follow Mike Campbell's sugggestion and added the following code to my view (`.html.erb') file

```
<SCRIPT type='text/Javascript'> 
$(function(){
  $('#form-id').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $('#seq_select').html(data);
  });
}
</SCRIPT>
```

and also gave an id to the form:

```
 <%= form_tag(:remote => true, :update => 'seq_select', :action => 'select', :id => 'form-id')  do %>
```

Submitting the form still doesn't update the page. It simply skips to a new rendered view as before. The generated HTML reads:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/Javascript'> 
$(function(){
  $('#form-id').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $('#seq_select').html(data);
  });
}
</SCRIPT>

<div id='seq_search'>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ajax_search/select/form-id?remote=true&amp;update=seq_select" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="wlOm4H7GvZAQoIVpjxPLqHAQLOIpJ4V5r0WYEpvCCrQ=" /></div>
    <p>
      <label> Search by identifiers, accessions, and gene names.. </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="query" name="query" size="45" type="search" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input disable_wth="Adding ..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form></div>

<div id='seq_select'>

</div>
```

Update:

It seems that the syntax for form_tag was wrong, and the first argument has to be the name of the action. I now have `<%= form_tag( 'select', :remote => true, :id => 'form_id')  do %>` which generates the associated HTML `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="select" data-remote="true" id="form_id" method="post">`. Which is better, but my Ajax is still not working.

Comment: You have the Rails JS/JQ gems/etc?

Comment: I don't think `:update` exists in Rails 3+. Looky here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044027/how-to-upgrade-the-update-div-id-option-of-remote-form-for-from-rails-2-to-r

Comment: @DaveNewton. let me look in to that.

Comment: @highBandWidth Mmm, yeah, Mike's right-if you're trying to update a div based on a remote form submit you'll want to bind to the completion/success.

Comment: @MikeCampbell: that looks ugly compared to Rails generating the JS for me. Anyway, is there a tutorial or the like for Ajax on Rails 3+?

Comment: @MikeCampbell, I tried the method you linked to, but my page still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with respond to xhr in the controller. you should specify this is a xhr request.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498694/how-to-respond-to-html-requests-made-via-ajax-in-rails) for a question on that.

Comment: That's what `:remote => true` does; the issue is on the client side.